# Boost не найден

Tags: cmake

Сделал git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 userver(https://github.com/userver-framework/service_template)
Запустил в Visual Studio, но не могу создать кэш CMake.
[image]

Было бы прекрасно, если вы объясните в чем я не прав и куда сувать boost, заранее большое вам спасибо!

Comment: @megorit в проекте нет FindBoost. Используются, вроде как, библиотеки, которые билдить не надо, или про что вы говорили? Boost_INCLUDE_DIR отсутствует. У меня Windows